# Where is the file of wallpaper of Dashboard on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I would like to know where it's exsited default wallpaper of Dashboard on Mavericks and how to change the wallpaper of Dashboard with default one. Because, It seems be changed by someone or when I create an account on my Mac. I'm not sure. But I would like to back previous one.

Could you tell me about it?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dock wallpaper is found at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock/` (to get to it in Finder choose `Go>Go To Folder…` from the Finder menu or hit Cmd-Shift-G)

The file you want called `dbgrid@2x.png` You'll need an admin password to change anything in that folder, and I'd advise you to make a backup before fiddling with it. You need to log out and in again for it to have any effect, or force quit and restart the dock (from a terminal `sudo kill Dock` will do that, then to restart it type `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock`).

If someone has removed the default, here it is (if anyone from Apple is worried about intelectual property it's a lookalike that I created with gimp on a debian system so it's all totally GPLicious. Yeah, right):

[image]

Comment: Could you someone to do "Vote up" due to no enough reputation